# Include master thesis summary on CV, or only the title?

Tags: resume, projects

Should I write a quick a summary of my master thesis in my CV, or I should write only the thesis title?

I've placed it at the section of the projects, but at the moment I have written only the title and the supervisor. I am looking for a PhD so I suppose that I will be asked about my master thesis many times; it will be written at my academic transcripts and I will speak about that at the interviews, I think.

It is tiring to mention it one more time? What do you think from your experience?

Comment: what general field is this?

Comment: Can you include your thesis title? It might be enough on its own but we can't say without seeing it. However, I notice you're talking about applying for a PhD - you might be better of asking over on academia.SE for what to do there

Answer (score 5):

If the thesis is very relevant for the application I would include a VERY brief summary, otherwise leave it out.

Stylistically it should be no more than maybe 2 lines longer than any other descriptions in the CV, if no others have descriptions/summaries then 3-4 lines.

Either way, if possible, a location to download or view the thesis should be included. If it has been published in a journal, presented at a conference, or is available through your university by some means, then include that in the form "Published in JournalA", "Presented at ConfB" or "Available through UniXs publishing platform UniXPapers".

Comment: My thesis, maybe will be very relevant, maybe shows  just how Ι worked in my master thesis if the field of my thesis is not the exact field Ι am looking for. When you say a VERY brief summary how many words you mean? No upload has yet been made of my thesis.

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis Don't think of "the CV". I suggest having a master CV which you can then adapt to different positions on an as-needed basis. That master version could have much more information which *may* be relevant to *some* job you can reasonably expect to apply to, so you might very well include a short summary of your thesis there, but before you submit it to a prospective employer, *prune ruthlessly* to remove everything that's not applicable to the position you are applying to, including the thesis summary.